# Has “SLComposeViewController” stopped pre-filling the initial text for Facebook share?

Tags: xcode, facebook, twitter

I have social share in my app implemented using Apples Social framework. 
Now Facebook share does bring sharing view controller up on screen but initial text missing. 
Has something changed?

Not only that cancelling call back is coming back as done [image]

[image]

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message part of a share. Go read Platform Policies please.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [SLComposeViewController setInitialText not showing up in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970741/slcomposeviewcontroller-setinitialtext-not-showing-up-in-view/30022380#30022380).

This behaviour is by design; prefilling was not allowed by policy, and now it's also enforced.

About the cancel button; this is a known issue and will be fixed. See bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/