# IOS setInitialText method in SLComposeViewController iOS 8.3 does not show text in Facebook sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, slcomposeviewcontroller

The Facebook sheet appears but contains no text. I am using XCode 6.3.1 and iOS 8.3 on an iPhone 6. Thank you in advance.

My code is

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[controller setInitialText:myStringObject];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Facebook does not want you to pre-fill text ven if user can edit or delete it. Check their [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) point 2.3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SLComposeViewController setInitialText not showing up in View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970741/slcomposeviewcontroller-setinitialtext-not-showing-up-in-view)

Comment: It's required by Facebook, you can't pre-fill it now