# Xcode Facebook Social Swift can't setInitialText

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm facing some problem with Social Framework. I'm trying to setInitialText to facebook but it's not working. I'm using the same code to setInitialText in Twitter and it's working greatly, but in Facebook is just working to setURL not a specific text.

I'm not wanting to post in users wall, i just want to suggest a text to post, and if he/she doesn't want, it can change anyway.

It was working but this week it stops.

P.S - I don't have facebook publish_action allowed in my facebook app.

How can I solve it? Is there a way?

Comment: That is not allowed according to Facebook Platform Policy. I suggest you read https://developers.facebook.com/policy and specifically 2.3

Comment: It seems to be an iOS bug (8.3). Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925810/slservicetypefacebook-setinitialtext-is-not-working

Comment: It isn't a bug - it is by design in the Facebook app - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/

Comment: I have looked at this link Paulw11 has posted. Really is a duplicate question and maybe with no answer! I uninstall the facebook app and it works to setInitialtext, if I reinstall, stops again. Is there a way to instead of use facebook app in newest update, i use social framework as if there is no facebook app installed?