# Cannot post to Facebook via SLComposeViewController (Social Framework)

Tags: ios, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `SLComposeViewController` for sharing in Facebook. 
While I didnt have Facebook installed on the device, the controller was coming up with texts pre filled as expected. After i installed Facebook, the `setPreText` is not showing.

Moreover, I cannot post to Facebook. Twitter is working fine.

My device has iOS8.

Comment: login with facebook in settings from iphone device

Comment: Ok, turned out i did login from the app but it not from settings.
So did that and its posting, But what about the initial text. How to solve that?

Comment: Supposing your device is on iOS8.3, it's a related bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/20709403

Answer (score 0):

A question related to your issue has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925810/slservicetypefacebook-setinitialtext-is-not-working). 
This [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/) has more details on why the `setInitialText:` does not work. Basically it is against the [Facebook platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) to pre-fill the share sheet.

> Pre-fill using the iOS share sheet. For apps pre-filling using the iOS
>   share sheet we recommend that you either remove all instances of
>   pre-fill from your app and submit an update to Apple's App Store or
>   use Facebook's share dialog for a more seamless experience.