# Share Image with Description in facebook swift 3

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, fbsdksharekit

I am trying to share an image with description to the facebook from my app using `FBSDKShareKit`. but the problem is, I am unable to add description with the image . 
Currently I have:

```
let content: FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
let photo:FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = imageView.image
photo.isUserGenerated = true
content.photos = [photo]
content.contentURL = URL(string:directUrl)
FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

I also have tried:

```
let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
vc?.add(imageview.image)
vc?.add(URL(string: "http://www.example.com/"))
vc?.setInitialText("description")
self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

using `social` ,In which `setInitialText` does not work  according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925810/slservicetypefacebook-setinitialtext-is-not-working) 
I tried this too: [image]

Is there any other way in which I can share image with description to fb?

Comment: Facebook is in the process of removing all ways to specify this data dynamically, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations This information will _only_ be taken from the Open Graph meta tags the shared URL returns.